# How to use intent settype to search text file of custom file extension

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I m using following code to open search intent to search text file in external storage:

```
private void performFileSearch()
{   
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("*text/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent,READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

But now I am going to create text file of custom file extension, for example textfile.tre, 
this file is not search able by this intent.
So i change type to :

```
 intent.setType("*/*");
```

Now intent is showing all the files. But I want to show only .tre file. What can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to show only .tre file

Sorry, but that is not possible. Android, like the Web, works on MIME types, not file extensions.